# How can I generate mesh for a portion of level-set surface using CGAL?

Tags: mesh, cgal, triangulation, implicit-surface

This is a question about the [3D Surface Mesh Generation](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesher/index.html#Chapter_3D_Surface_Mesh_Generation) tool in CGAL.

According to the documentation, I need to provide the surface to be meshed in implicit-form as a zero level-set surface. This seems to place a restriction on the input surface to be manifold.

**The Problem**

In my use-case, I need to generate mesh for a small 'region' of an otherwise larger 'parent' manifold implicit surface. The 'region' itself is non-manifold because it does not enclose a volume.

[image]

A way I can think of for tackling this is :

- Mesh the entire 'parent' surface, and then
- Extract the mesh corresponding to the required 'region'.

However, I want to avoid this for performance reasons.

How should I proceed with this ?
Is any other module available in CGAL that can help me achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

As your surface is implicit, you can easily create function that represents the intersection of that implicit surface with an implicit volume, like a sphere, a bounding box, or a half-space.

Let's, for example, that you have the equation of a sphere:

```cpp
auto sphere(double x, double, y, double z) {
  return x*x + y*y + z*z - 1;
}
```

then you can compute the intersection with a half-space, like that:

```cpp
auto half_space(double x, double y, double z) {
  return y - x > 0 ? -1. : -1.;
}

auto intersection(double, x, double y, double z) {
  if(half_space(x, y, z) > 0) return 1.
  else return sphere(x, y,  z);
}
```